# Maximize window in MacVim on startup

Tags: macvim

How can I set MacVim to start up with a window that extends the full height (minus menu bar) and width of my monitor (not fullview)?

If this impossible on startup, how can I change it manually (not by dragging the window, but with a command)?

Comment: Does clicking the '+' button count as a command? Having lots of smaller windows is a kind of "Mac" thing. Just maximise it when you open it.

Comment: To toggle maximize use Ctrl-Command-F shortcut in MacVim

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the `lines` and `columns` options. Just use “very large” values and Vim will truncate them to the largest possible values for your screen and font sizes. If you put this in your `~/.gvimrc`, then your initial window will automatically be sized accordingly.

```
set lines=999 columns=9999
```

See `:help 'lines'` and `:help 'columns'` for the details.

---

MacVim also has the `fullscreen` and `fuoptions` options (along with the “Prefer native full-screen support” checkbox in the *Advanced* section of the **MacVim** > **Preferences…** dialog) that you might find useful.

Comment: Fullscreen is just that - Fullscreen. An d it takes more time to switch to that.